# set where the derivative of a continuos function is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have looked at some questions about the set of non-differentiability of a function but I could not find a definite answer. My question is the following:

Considering a $f \in \mathcal{C}$ is the set $I(a,b):= \{x: f^\prime(x)= \infty, \ x \in [a,b]  \}$ totally disconnected?

Here is an attempt for a proof:

We construct a function
    $$
       F(x) := f(x) - \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} (x-a) 
    $$ 
    We observe that $F(a)= f(a)$ and $F(b)= f(a)$. 
    Then 
    $$
     F^\prime (x) = f^{\prime}(x) - \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}
    $$
Suppose that $f^{\prime}(x)= \infty$ uniformly in $[a,b]$.
Then $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function then so is $F(x)$ so that $F(b)>F(a)$.
However, $F(a)= F(b)$ by construction, which is a contradiction.
Therefore, there is a number $c \in (a, b)$, such that $f^\prime(c) < \infty$.
   However, we can apply the same reasoning to $[a, c]$ , resp to $[c, b]$.
        Therefore, by the Nested Intervals Theorem only $f^{\prime}(a)=\infty$.
        Therefore, $f^{\prime}(x)= \infty$ does not hold uniformly in $[a,b]$.

Comment: I don't think this question is well defined.  Setting f'=\inf doesn't really mean anything with some clarification.

Comment: I can add a hypothesis that f is non-decreasing but the question is about the  set where the derivative is infinite.

Comment: What do you mean by $f'(x) = \infty$? Do you mean the function behaves like a vertical line around $x$? Generally we define the derivative of a function at a point $x$ if that limit exists, which in particular means it is finite. You need to give a precise definition of what you mean by $f'(x) = \infty$.

Comment: f'=\inf is equivilant to daying that dx/dy=0.  Because this is true everywhere  then f is nowhere increasing and no where decreasing.  In fact f is either a straight line or everywhere discontinuous.

Comment: Actually dx/dy= 0 implies that f is continuous on I which answers your question.  I is not disconnected.

Comment: You are implying that f is invertible, which is an extra assumption.

Comment: The problem with your question is, that for the limit $lim_{a \to b} \frac {f(a)-f(b)} {a-b} $ to be infinite, the function has to be discontinuous at b, so the set is actually empty. If you replace "continuous" by "monotone" this has a nice answer, I think.